# Does Angel of Jubliation prevent repeating Lim-Dûl's Vault?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Angel of Jubilation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20of%20Jubilation%5d) stop people from paying life for [Lim-Dûl's Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLim-D%c3%bbl%27s%5d%2b%5bVault%5d)? My understanding is that it does not, since paying life is part of the resolution of the spell, but Magic the Gathering's rules never fail to surprise, so I figured I'd ask to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, it does not prevent the cost to repeat the effect of vault. [Angel of Jubilation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20of%20Jubilation%5d) specifically stops you from paying life or sacrificing creatures as a cost of casting, this is not a cast. From the rulings on Angel of Jubilation:

[Emphasis mine]

> Other things may still cause players to pay life or sacrifice creatures, **such as a resolving spell** or ability.

What would prevent this is something like [Platinum Emperion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlatinum%20Emperion%5d).

Comment: Just to add an example the other way, the angel would prevent someone from playing [Fumarole](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=184626). Note the "as an additional cost to cast" phrasing in the (oracle) rules text of the card.